# Using Django Restframework to create Single User Sign On

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, single-sign-on

I am currently using the Django Rest Framework.
However an external cloud service provider would require a SSO.

I was browsing through some answers but didn't get anything helpful.

I can authenticate the user for the api

```
curl -X POST -d "email=useremail&password=password" 127.0.0.1:8000
```

I get the token back.
Now i can make api requests.

I read something about using SAML, however all the packages are outdated.

I was thinking about rewriting the authentication() function, to take in the username and the token to verify the user and redirect him to the App Dashboard.

To clarify an external Cloud Service is trying to log in a user into our APP with a direct link.

I can't find a nice, clean approach to use here.

I don't think i should use something like request.GET.get('username') request.GET.get('password') because i don't think that will be very secure.

On the other hand the curl call is pretty much doing the same thing to get the token.

Any Advice, Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the python-saml library?
https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml

Comment: Thank you! Looks promising did you implement it?

Comment: I used it only.